# error: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Tags: laravel, ssl, openssl, vagrant, homestead

While running the command `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`, I am getting this error:

> An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
>   message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
>   again.
>
> OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Can you help me?

Comment: I got the same error when my internet connection had lost 

Comment: It's not a duplicate

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I got the answer by some searching on GitHub,

replace this  `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` with

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead http://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
```

Comment: better use vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead

Comment: @ShahadatHossainKhan to avoid confusion `--insecure` do still download from `https://`, it just didn't validate the SSL certificates. In case if people expecting it will downloading from `http://`

Comment: Btw i also just tested options `--insecure`. still got error

`An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54`

Comment: @GusDeCooL off-course it download from https:// unless you didn't configure explicitly your vagrant. by using --insecure you send a flag that you have no problem for any (expired) ssl certificate. and really i don't fetch the error you facing with that option, you have to google it for this issue :D

Comment: Agreed, looks like the issue on my ISP side :(
Tested with VPN it's working fine.

Comment: Gee! Thanks for this. It solved the problem I've been having for more than 4 days. Even upgraded to Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.5 Beta! Thanks!!!

Comment: I just clicked clone again in visual studio and it worked a second time