# Vagrant box add laravel/homestead error 10045

Tags: laravel, ssl, openssl

Hi i'm new in lumen Laravel and i wanted to install laravel/homestead virtual machine.

so i installed virtual box latest and i have installed Vagrant as well and i have enabled Hyper-V, But once i tried to add the laravel/homestead box to my Vagrant installation using the following command in my terminal:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

I got that problem for both my choice Virtual Box or Hyper-V

```
C:\Users\LE>vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.

1) hyperv
2) parallels
3) virtualbox
4) vmware_desktop

Enter your choice: 1
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v5.1.0) for provider: hyperv
    box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/5.1.0/providers/hy
perv.box
    box: Progress: 1% (Rate: 0/s, Estimated time remaining: 19:08:21)50))
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
```

i have tryed the solution given in this link 
[error: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912076/error-openssl-ssl-read-ssl-error-syscall-errno-10054)
i got this pb

```
The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

seem that is outdated the link to atlas.

I tryed another proposition but no one worked for me.

Please let me know if anyone familiar this type of error.

Comment: If SSL is not mandatory for you, check the comment on answer you linked.

Comment: sorry i did not got what do u mean exactly

Comment: ah ok u mean do :' use vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead ' it does not work for me tooo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Some developers pay my intention to very interest point that i want to share :

- try to download manually the box, here is an old manual => 
  https://gist.github.com/.../deec25b8fa54976edb496d7ce7d320a7
  you can check for the new one
- At the end if you use *unix you do not need to use homestead, instead to lost time to use vagran/homestead install the packages you need, all the packages are listed here => https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead#introduction

> If you run on windows, I agree it's a difficult to develop at the end.

- if you are on windows, you should take a look at  **laragon** . it will save you time and effort to install homestead.

  Because even if you run homestead on windows you will have difficulties in development, for example, the watch system needs configuration and is **slow**.
  In the other hand, you can easily **switch php versions on Laragon**.
- you may have multiple problems with windows and this is why I hate it, Laragon is very good (for Windows ), but you may have problems, and many extensions are not enabled by default (sqlite, as example).

**Xampp** in my opinion can be better than **Laragon**, I spent countless hours figuring out different problems with Laragon.

If you need to speed up, finish some work, you can try Laragon, if you are going to work on big thing, and use multiple APIs, databases..ect
I suggest you take sometime and switch to Linux, it takes sometime but worth it after everything installed!

There is a channel in youtube, specialized in WordPress and PHP, they show how to install Linux (elementary OS) with Lamp stack, they make it pretty as Mac OSX, I even get stuck on updating PHP, 7.1 to 7.2

- Now I am using **Fedora** which is awesome, in my opinion, so you are free what to choose between all this jargon.

Wish that the answer is useful at least for whom uses windows like me.