# error in setting up vagrant as local development environment

Tags: laravel, openssl, vagrant, virtualbox

I have vagrant **(Vagrant 2.0.4)** and Oracle VM Virtual Box **(Version 5.2.10 r122406 (Qt5.6.2))** installed on my machine.

As soon as I enter `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` or `vagrant box add laravel/homestead http://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead` on Git Bash, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
>   message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
>   again. OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering, what command I need to enter on my Git Bash so that I am successfully able to **laravel/homestead for virtualbox**.

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912076/error-openssl-ssl-read-ssl-error-syscall-errno-10054), but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try emptying the temp first by running this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/
```

then running the following command:

```
vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead
```

if this doesn't work ,then empty your temp by :

1. pressing win +r
2. typing %temp% then hitting enter
3. then delete everything in there and if asked to continue or skip, choose skip
   then connect to a VPN and try running the following command :

   vagrant box add laravel/homestead

hope this helps.