# I can't push commit to github repository

Tags: git, github

I can't push my game files to git repository.
I have a github pro account.
I set git config http.postBuffer 524288000, sslVerify = `false` and the problem still exists.

[image: Screenshot of error]

On commit push by sourcetree
Error: rpc failed curl 56 openssl ssl_read ssl_error_syscall errno 10054

Comment: I suggest you update your question with the error message you see. It might not be easy to discern from the screenshot.

Comment: Done, I update my post

Comment: Have you tried this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45912076/4851565

Answer (score 1):

The errno value 10054 means that the remote host closed the connection. That can mean a variety of things:

- Your connection is too slow to push all of the data, and the connection timed out.
- Your connection is spotty and enough packets got lost that the connection was closed.
- The remote side hung up on you in an unexpected way, perhaps due to a permissions error or being overloaded, although this would be extremely uncommon.
- You're using some software or VM infrastructure that caused the network connection to be broken, such as an antivirus program or an old version of Vagrant.

All of these things (and more) can cause this error, but ultimately the network connection was dropped, leading to the error. Setting `http.sslVerify` and `http.postBuffer` won't help here, and the former is just weakening your security.